Spring batch 5.2 running at application startup
I am using spring boot 3.4 below is my BatchConfig. It's running at startup of the application even I have added required property to disabled at start:
    @Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class BatchConfig {

    private static final int BATCH_SIZE = 1000;

    private final EmployeeReadService readService;
    private final EmployeeWriteService writeService;
    private final EmployeeProcessService processService;
    private final JobRepository jobRepository;
    private final PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager;


    // Job Configuration
    @Bean
    public Job migrationJob(Step migrateStep) {
        return new JobBuilder("migrationJob", jobRepository)
                .start(migrateStep)
                .preventRestart()
                .build();
    }
    // Step Configuration
    @Bean
    public Step migrateStep() throws Exception {
        return new StepBuilder("migrateStep", jobRepository)
                .<SourceEmployee, DestinationEmployee>chunk(BATCH_SIZE, transactionManager)
                .reader(readService.reader()) // Paginated reader
                .processor(processService.processor())
                .writer(writeService.writer())
                .build();
    }
}

application.yml:
spring:
  batch:
    job:
      enabled: false
  h2:
    console:
      enabled: true
      path: /h2-console
  sql:
    init:
      mode: always
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:h2:mem:testdb;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE
    driver-class-name: org.h2.Driver
    username: sa
    password:
    jpa:
        hibernate:
            ddl-auto: create-drop
        show-sql: true


Have you tried to remove @EnableBatchProcessing? With that annotation, the batch auto-configuration (including batch properties interpretation) is disabled.
